# How to write routes when params with variable length?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Because of the design of the website url, the params will be changed, so there is no way to fix the number of params. How to edit the app-routing.module.ts in this way?

```
url => /products/cat1/cat2/cat3/cat4 ...
```

```js
const routes: Routes = [
   
    {
        path: 'products/:cat1/:cat2 ...', // how to do it ??
        component: ProductsComponent,
    }
 ]
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I enter the URL, I can go to the component I want
browser url  =>  /products/cat1/cat2/cat3/cat4 ...
coming to ProductsComponent

Answer (score 0):

You should pass ids as `queryParam` like:

```
this.router.navigate(['products'], {queryParams: {categories: [cat1, cat2, cat3]}});
```

Then in your `ProductsComponent`:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({ ... })
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: number[];
  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.categories = params.categories;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And your route will be like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsComponent,
  }
]
```